# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'int'

Tags: python

```
def projet_catapulte(point_de_vie_1, point_de_vie_2) :
    """ Jeu de catapulte joueur1 vs joueur2 tour à tour  """
    assert isinstance(point_de_vie_1, (int)), "Type a incorrect, il faut un int "    # controle des types
    assert isinstance(point_de_vie_2, (int)), "Type b incorrect, il faut un int"    # des arguments 

    #var
    point_d_impact=0.0   #float
    temps=0.0            #float
    i=0                  #int
    j=1                  #int
    angle=0.0            #float
    #begin
    point_de_vie_1=20
    point_de_vie_2=20
    while point_de_vie_1 > 0 or point_de_vie_2 > 0 :
        #begin
        i=1
        while i > 0 :
            #begin
            print("joueur_1 joue")
            angle=int(input("Entrez l'angle : "))
            temps=(temps_appuie)
            point_d_impact=((temps*angle)/38)
            print(point_d_impact)
```

Really don't know this typeError

Answer (score 1):

`temps_appuie` is a function, and you've put a reference to it into `temps`. Perhaps you meant to call it instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
temps=(temps_appuie)
```

You are making `temps` to point to a function. So, in this statement

```
point_d_impact=((temps*angle)/38)
```

you are multiplying a function with `angle` which is a number. Thats why it fails. Did you mean to call the function like this?

```
temps=temps_appuie()
```